# What is the most performant way to group by and join high cardinality columns in column based table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, query-performance, index, columnstore

I currently have a SQL Server, 20 column fact table that could grow even wider into the hundreds. The current row count is about 9 million records. The indexing strategy is currently row-based. The query joins to every lookup table totaling about a dozen joins (most columns in the table are FKs). This is an analytical table that is generated nightly. Query filters are ad hoc so row-indexing most permutations is not feasible. I would like to explore removing these joins and using a columnstore index, since for the most part, only a handful of filter columns will be specified per query request.

**Given I have three tables:**

Table 1: SomeFactTable (~9 million records)

```
| Column         | Description          | Cardinality                   |
| --------       | --------------       | --------------                |
| Id             | int32 PK             | Unique                        |
| Timestamp      | datetime, non-null   | medium                        |
| LookupTableA_ID| int32, non-null, FK  | Medium-high (40k records)     |
| LookupTableB_ID| int32, non-null, FK  | Low (dozens records)          |
| NumberA        | int32, non-null      | Very high (8 million records) |
```

Table 2: LookupTableA (~40,000 records)

```
| Column      | Description            | Cardinality    |
| --------    | --------------         | -------------- |
| Id          | int32 PK               | Unique         |
| Description | varchar(255), non-null | high           |
```

Table 3: LookupTableB (~50 records)

```
| Column      | Description            | Cardinality    |
| --------    | --------------         | -------------- |
| Id          | int32 PK               | Unique         |
| Description | varchar(255), non-null | high           |
```

**I have two questions.**

1. How can I combine the benefits of a columnstore index with also grouping on the high cardinality NumberA column?

For example, given this query, it performs in about 100ms (which is great!). If I uncomment the group by `NumberA`, then the performance degrades to ~900ms (good, but I'd like to do better).

```
SELECT 
  max(Id) Id
  ,[Timestamp] 
FROM 
  [dbo].[SomeFactTable]
group by 
  [Timestamp]  
  --,NumberA
ORDER BY 
  [Timestamp] ASC 
OFFSET 500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

2. Most of the time I need to order by one or more of the lookup tables which requires a join. Sometimes these tables have many records (e.g. LookupTableA) and sometimes they only have a handful (e.g. LookupTableB). When there are many records, then the performance degrades. When there are only a handful, then the performance does not degrade. How can I maintain high performance when the table has many records?

As an example, this is a join with medium cardinality. It also has the high cardinality column from question 1. The query returns in about 2,900 ms.

```
SELECT 
  max(SomeFactTable.Id) Id, 
  [Timestamp],
  [Description]
FROM 
  dbo.SomeFactTable
  INNER JOIN dbo.LookupTableA ON SomeFactTable.LookupTableA_ID = LookupTableA.Id 
group by 
  [Timestamp], 
  [Description], 
  NumberA
ORDER BY 
  [Description] ASC, 
  [DateAbsent] ASC 
OFFSET 500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

This is a join with low cardinality. It also has the high cardinality column from question 1. The query returns in about 1,000 ms (and returns even much faster if NumberA wasn't grouped).

```
SELECT 
  max(SomeFactTable.Id) Id, 
  [Timestamp],
  [Description]
FROM 
  dbo.SomeFactTable
  INNER JOIN dbo.LookupTableB ON SomeFactTable.LookupTableB_ID = LookupTableB.Id 
group by 
  [Timestamp], 
  [Description], 
  NumberA
ORDER BY 
  [Description] ASC, 
  [DateAbsent] ASC 
OFFSET 500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

I only have a little bit of experience with **columnstore indexing**, but my experience has been awesomely positive so far. I'm assuming when you say the cardinality of the `SomeFactTable.NumberA` column  is ~8 million of the ~9 million records, that you mean they share the same value. If so, then I think a **columnstore index** would work great for you on it, because it compresses the data of the columns it encompasses, and ~8 million / ~9 million records would be about a 90% compression ratio.

Again I'm no expert but I'd recommend testing a columnstore index on just the `(NumberA)` column vs one on all the fields you might group on, i.e. `(Timestamp, Description, NumberA)`.